# Hadoop Configuration - Cluster

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, configuration, cluster-computing

what is the correct setting for the files core-site.xml and mapred-site.xml for Hadoop?
Because I'm trying to run hadoop but get the following error:

starting secondarynamenode , logging to / opt/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hadoop-secondarynamenode-lbad012.out

lbad012 : Exception in thread “main ” java.lang.IllegalArgumentException : Does not contain a valid host : port authority : file :/ / /

lbad012 : at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr ( NetUtils.java : 164 )

lbad012 : at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getAddress ( NameNode.java : 212 )

lbad012 : at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getAddress ( NameNode.java : 244 )

lbad012 : at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getServiceAddress ( NameNode.java : 236 )

lbad012 : at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.initialize ( SecondaryNameNode.java : 194 )

lbad012 : at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode . ( SecondaryNameNode.java : 150 )

lbad012 : at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.main ( SecondaryNameNode.java : 676 )

Comment: what are your current settings?

Comment: this is core-site.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://lbad012:9000</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.permissions</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
</configuration>

and this is mapred-site.xml

<configuration>
<property>
        <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
        <value>lbad012:9001</value>
</property>
</configuration>

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which version of hadoop you're using, or whether or not you're using CDH (cloudera's hadoop distro)

You also didn't specify whether or not you're looking to run in a pseudo-distributed, single node, or distributed cluster setup.  These options specifically are set up in the files youre mentioning (core-site and mapred-site)

Hadoop is very finicky so these details are important when asking questions related to hadoop.

Since you didn't specify any of the above though, Im guessing you're a beginner -- in which case [this guide](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/02/hadoop-pseudo-distributed-installation/) should help you (and show you what core-site and mapred-site should look like in a pseudo-distributed configuration)

Anyway, Hadoop has a 'Quick Start' guide for almost every version of hadoop they upload, so find one that relates to the version and setup you're looking for and it should be fairly easy to walk through.

Comment: I'm using this version 1.2.1 and I'm not using anything cloudera and what I intend to accomplish is a multi-node cluster with 1 master machine and 3 slaves machine.
any more information is necessary?

Comment: Okay, [here you go then](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/cluster_setup.html)

Comment: Frankie Thanks for the tip, but I've read and reread and still can not find what could be wrong.

Comment: Rodrigo, reading over and triple-checking are going to be a part of this process haha, just warning.  

From a quick glance at the config files you posted, they look okay -- i would have configured the other recommended fields but i think it would work anyway.  First things first: make sure the host lbad012 is available, but since the config files look okay, maybe you arent running hadoop in the correct directory and it isnt sucking in those config files (more common than you'd think) 

[related discussion here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-2515)

Comment: I checked the configuration of the core-site.xml and also checked the communication between machines via ssh and also if I'm in the correct folder and everything is ok.